# How can I check for matches when analizing a string character by character?

Tags: python

I am trying to program an assembler and the way I do it is the following: First I get get the program, split it in lines. After that, I treat each line individually, split each line into characters including everything and I am stuck now because I do not know how to check for matches, for example: how would I check for the opcode "LOAD" the register "R1" and the data value "18" in a list such as ["L", "O", "A", "D", " ", "R", "1", ",", "1", "8"]? Please, help is appreciated.

Comment: [maybe related: how-do-you-make-an-assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478142/how-do-you-make-an-assembler)

Comment: Why split `LOAD R1,18` into `["L", "O", "A", "D", " ", "R", "1", ",", "1", "8"]` instead of `["LOAD", "R1", "18"]`?

Comment: It might be helpful to show your code (or at least some example code that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: You need to define the grammar of your assembly language.  If all instructions are always of the form `opcode operand[,operands...]`, then you can just split on whitespace to separate `opcode` from `operands`, and then split `operands` on `,` to break it into pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Before you split the line into characters you could split it into words like below list.  The if statement then can check for items in the list.

```
x=["This", "apple","is","red"]
if "This" in x:
    print "yes"
```

Updated answer per comments below.

```
line="MD=D+1"
if "MD" in line:
    print "Do something"
```

Updated to get command out of line.

```
line="MD=D+1"
if "MD" in line:
    print line.split("MD")
    command=line.split("MD")[1] #get second element in list
    print command
    #now you can parse command to do something with it.
```

Comment: Zack, that would work but, each instruction treats parameters differently.

Comment: Mouviciel, that was just an example.

Comment: The actual code I am trying to assemble looks something like "MD=D+1" and it does not contain spaces.

Comment: So you are trying to find "MD" inside of "MD=D+1"?

Comment: I am trying to find "MD" and then make it realize which parameters to expect and how to treat them.

Comment: What parameters and treat them in what way? Please give me an example in some sudo python code.

Comment: I have nothing written yet, it's all flow charts.

Comment: We cannot help really without the code.  Hopefully my code gets you started but really we need a nice MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `characterLine = ["M", "D", "=", "D", "+", "1"]
characterCounter = ""
for char in characterLine:
    characterCounter = characterCounter + x
    if characterCounter == "MD":
        print("What do I do now")`

Comment: The challenge is you are splitting it into characters so my original will not work.  But you want something that says if "MD" is in line  do something? Correct?

Comment: Exactly, Zack :D!

Comment: Please see updated answer. If this is what you need please accept the answer. :D

Comment: But wait, what I want to do after finding "MD" is manipulate the other parameters ("=D+1") but those are split into individual characters too D:!

Comment: Okay so do not split them into characters. Just keep it as a line.  One sec and let me test.

Comment: I have updated it so you can get a "command" which in this case will be a string with "=D+1". Then you will need to do something with that "=D+1" but I need you to write code from here and test.  Then if you have issues we can help later on.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to concatenate the Strings in an new str.
Then, you can use split method on your string to create a charList.

> str1 = 'LOAD", str2 = 'R1', str3`= '8`
>
> ```
> strN = str1 + " " + str2 + " " + str3
> result = strN.split()
> print(result)
> ```

Comment: I dont think that is what he is asking.