# How to tell the length of an x86 instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, code-size, instruction-encoding

I was looking at the different instructions in assembly and I am confused on how the lengths of different operands and opcodes are decided upon.

Is it something you *ought* to know from experience, or is there a way to find out which operand/operator combination takes up how many bytes?

For eg:

```
push %ebp ; takes up one byte
mov %esp, %ebp ; takes up two bytes
```

So the question is:

Upon seeing a given instruction, how can I deduce how many bytes its opcode will require?

Comment: Writing an x86 disassembler is a very challenging task. There is no simple rule to know how long an instruction is as there is no system for which opcode receives what operands. Prefixes make this even more complicated because they can influence what operands the instruction takes.

Comment: Even learning the x86 assembly *is* a **very complicated** task. Building a disassembler is like 10x more complicated than that. Without a deep understanding of x86 assembly and a dozen other things, it makes hardly any sense to start a writing a disassembler.

Comment: You mean the machine code for the whole instruction (including prefixes and operands), not just the opcode.

Comment: related [How to write a disassembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924303/995714)

Comment: Related: [How does the CPU know how many bytes it should read for the next instruction, considering instructions have different lengths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56385995)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule for x86 without a database as the instruction encoding is pretty complex (and the opcode itself can vary from 1 to 3 bytes).  You can consult the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual 2A](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf) document (Chapter 2: Instruction Format) to see how instructions and their operands are encoded:

[image]

Comment: Yes, In other architectures instructions are cataloged by type (Register-Register, Storage-Register, Storage-Storage, etc) and each type has a clearly established length.

Answer (score 11):

So, since this topic seems to interest you, let me give you an overview. An x86 instruction comprises up to five parts and is up to 15 bytes long:

```
prefixes opcode operand displacement immediate
```

It is possible to generate encodings that are longer than 15 bytes, but the CPU rejects them. All five parts except for the opcode are optional. You can find their length as follows:

- an instruction can have any number of *legacy prefixes*. These are: `f0` **lock**, `f2` **repne**, `f3` **repe**, `2e` **cs**, `36` **ss**, `3e` **ds**, `26` **es**, `64` **fs**, `65` **gs**, `66` operand size override, and `67` address size override. However, only one of `f0`, `f2`, `f3` and only one of `26`, `2e`, `36`, `3e`, `64`, and `65` is recognized at a time. If more than one prefix from each group is provided, CPUs behave differently. VEX and EVEX encoded instructions may only have the segment override and address size override legacy prefixes as the other prefixes are subsumed under the VEX and EVEX prefixes.
- In long mode (and only there), an instruction may have a *REX prefix* immediately after all legacy prefixes. The REX prefix is one of `40` to `4f`. In other modes, these bytes are instructions, not prefixes and your decoder must account for that. As with legacy prefixes, a VEX or EVEX encoded instruction cannot have a REX prefix.
- The bytes `c4` and `c5` can introduce a *VEX prefix* used to encode some modern instructions. In long mode, they always do, but in other modes, you have to check the byte afterwards: Interprete it as a modr/m byte, if it encodes an `r,r` operand pair, it's a VEX prefix, otherwise its the opcode for `les` or `lds`. A VEX prefix beginning with `c4` is two bytes long, with `c5` it's three bytes.  The VEX prefix also encodes the `0f`, `0f 38` and `0f 3a` opcode prefixes which are omitted in a VEX encoded instruction. Note that generally, using a VEX prefix is not optional. For example, `pdep` is encoded as `VEX.NDS.LZ.F2.0F38.W0 F5 /r` (e.g. `c4 e2 7b f5 c0` for `pdep eax,eax,eax`) but the corresponding legacy instruction `f2 0f 38 f5 r/m32` (e.g. `f2 0f 38 f5 c0` for `pdep eax,eax`) is invalid. Note that the same opcode can exist with a VEX prefix and without and the two can mean different things. For example, `0f 77` is `emms` but `VEX.128.0F.WIG 77` (i.e. `c5 f8 77`) is `vzeroupper`.
- The byte `62` introduces an *EVEX prefix* which is used to encode AVX512 instructions.  Similar to the VEX prefix, the next few bytes need to be checked to distinguish an EVEX prefix from the `bound` instruction.  The EVEX prefix is always four bytes long and encodes part of the opcode just as the VEX prefix does.

After the prefixes, the opcode follows. Originally, the opcode was always a single byte but then they ran out of space, so now it's either a single byte or a single byte prefixed by `0f`, `0f 38`, or `0f 3a`. These prefixes are absent if the instruction is VEX encoded. Note that some prefixes may change what instruction is encoded. For example, opcode `0f b8` is `jmpe` (Enter IA-64 mode) but `f3 0f b8` is not `repe jmpe` but rather `popcnt`.

The opcode and the prefixes decide which instruction is encoded. From here on, it's mostly smooth sailing. Depending on the instruction, a *modr/m* byte may follow. Depending on the modr/m byte and the address override prefix, a *sib byte* and one, two, or four *displacement bytes* may follow. Finally, depending on the instruction, the operand size override prefix, and the REX prefix, one, two, four, six, or eight *immediate bytes* may follow.

That's about as much of a description as I can give in the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. So **TL;DR:** It's really complicated.

Comment: After reading your answer i think writing an disassembler is long way to learn x86 assembly. Thanks for info.

Comment: @moien That's a good idea. x86 has the most difficult instruction encoding of all architectures I know.

Comment: so you mean EVEX is only available in long mode? But according to wiki it seems EVEX is supported in 32-bit mode [EVEX coding can address 8 operand mask registers, 16 general-purpose registers and 32 vector registers in 64-bit mode (otherwise, 8 general-purpose and 8 vector), and can support up to 4 operands.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVEX_prefix)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I recall reading somewhere that AVX-512 was not available in 32 bit mode.  Perhaps I am wrong about that.

Comment: yeah I've checked the Intel manual and there's *Table 2-32.  EVEX Encoding Register Specifiers in 32-bit Mode* in the instruction format section

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Interesting!  I have already updated the answer, I hope it's better now.  I wonder how they distinguish EVEX from `bound`.

Comment: I wondered that too when I read about VEX. In VEX it's differentiated by mod=11b in 32-bit mode, but I don't know why EVEX uses mod=00b

Comment: I've asked a question regarding that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853237/995714)

Answer (score 9):

Terminology: ["opcode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) is the part of the instruction that selects the operation, not including operands, or non-mandatory prefixes that modify the operation (e.g. operand-size).  Using "opcode" to refer to the whole instruction is incorrect, although done fairly often by some people talking about shellcode.

> Is it something you ought to know from experience

With experience looking at machine code or especially experience optimizing for code-size, then yes, you'll start to remember things you've looked up repeatedly, and learn how to look at an asm line and know how long the instruction will be, without memorizing *what* the bytes will be.

The operand-encoding rules don't depend on the opcode, so you just have to remember the opcode lengths, and the special-case short forms that don't use a ModR/M byte to encode operands.  And then separately remember the operand-encoding rules.

For me personally, I like to answer [code-golf questions like this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133618/extreme-fibonacci/135618#135618) with x86 machine code.  (**See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code)**).  I write in NASM, planning / knowing how long each instruction will be, and let the assembler generate the hexdump of the actual machine code as a listing.  For the short instructions that are useful for code-golf, I don't remember having been wrong about instruction length any time recently, but I'm lucky to have a good memory for details (like the x86 instruction set) that I find interesting or use a lot.  (I did have to try `rorx` to see how long it was.)

I don't type out the machine-code bytes myself; to do that by hand I'd have to look each instruction up in the manual.  x86 doesn't have short encodings for PC-relative addressing, so finding/creating useful constants inside the machine code (that could double as data) is not a thing, so it's not generally useful for code-golf to memorize any of the numeric details of instruction encoding.

When optimizing for performance, smaller is usually better when everything else is equal, so caring about code-size and especially alignment is definitely part of performance.

> or is there a way to find out which operand/operator combination takes up how many bytes?

This is well documented in manuals.  Other than a few special-case 1-byte instructions, operand encoding is the same for (almost) everything.

---

The machine-code encoding of most x86 instructions follow this pattern (better diagram version of this from Intel in [@Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567903/instruction-lengths/4567927#4567927)):

```
[prefixes] opcode ModR/M [extra addressing-mode bytes] [immediate]
```

(Instructions with no explicit operands don't have a ModR/M byte, just the opcode byte(s)).

x86 opcodes are 1 byte for most common instructions, especially instructions which have existed since 8086.  Instructions added later (e.g. like `bsf` and `movsx` in 386) often use 2-byte opcodes with a `0f` escape byte.  If you hang around on SO, you'll see a lot of questions asking about 8086 specifically (especially `emu8086`); that's the main reason I know something about which instructions weren't available on 8086.  If you'd rather just remember directly which instructions have 2-byte opcodes without the historical details, that's totally fine.  Or just look it up every time in the manual :P

e.g. `0f b6 c0   movzx  eax,al`, so 0F B6 is the opcode for `mov r32, r/m8`, and C0 is the ModR/M byte that encodes eax as the destination (`/r` field = 0), register direct mode for the source (top 2 bits = 11), and `al` as the source register (`/m` field = 0).

I'm using Intel syntax for all my examples (`mnemonic dst, src1 [,src2, ...]`) because that matches what you'll find in Intel and AMD's manuals.  AFAIK, there aren't any detailed instruction-encoding manuals that use AT&T syntax.  I'm also using 32 or 64-bit examples even when talking about what 8086 had.  Of course 8086 only had 16-bit real mode, but the same opcode and encoding is used in 64-bit mode (which is what we care about these days).

---

[Intel's instruction set ref. manual (SDM vol.2)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) has opcode maps for 1, 2, 3 byte opcodes (appendix A.3), so you can see some patterns in the choice of opcode encoding.  Or for any given instruction, look at the encoding listed along with the full description in that manual.  (Also see some nice online extracts with one page per instruction, like https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki and http://felixcloutier.com/x86/.  HJ Lebbink's page tags each instruction with when it was introduced, so you can see 8086 for `add`, or 386 for new forms of shifts, and for `movzx`).

Note that some one-operand instructions, like [`shl`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SAL_SAR_SHL_SHR) or `not`, use the `/r` field of the ModR/M byte as extra opcode bits.  Also most instructions with an immediate are still destructive because they use the `/r` field as opcode bits.  `imul r32, r/m32, imm32` (386) is the exception to this rule, having an immediate and using the full ModR/M byte for both operands.  (Note that the ModR/M can only signal register or memory operands; the encoding for `add r/m32, imm8` uses the opcode to indicate that there's an immediate.  But the main opcode byte is shared by multiple instructions, so the `/r` field is used as part of the opcode, and *that's* why we don't have `add r/m32, r32, imm8`.  But for ADD / SUB we can use `lea ecx, [rax + 1]` as a copy-and-add.)

---

#### Operand encoding:

Most instructions with an immediate operand are the same length as the register/memory source version, plus the bytes to encode the immediate.  Immediates are either imm8 or imm32, so values from -128..127 are more compact.   (In 16-bit mode it's either imm8 or imm16).

The ModR/M byte is all that's needed for register direct, or the simplest one-register addressing mode with no displacement.  (Except with `[esp]`).  So `add eax, ecx` is 2 bytes long, just like `add eax, [ecx]`.  Indexed addressing modes (and modes with `esp` / `rsp` as the base register) need a SIB (Scale/Index/Base) byte.

Constant displacements in addressing modes need an extra 1 or 4 bytes (sign-extended disp8 or disp32) on top of the ModR/M + optional SIB.

AVX512 EVEX with disp8 scales the disp8 by the vector width, so [`vaddps zmm31, zmm30, [rsi + 256]`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/ADDPS) is only 7 bytes (4-byte EVX + opcode=0x58 + modrm + disp8), but `vaddps zmm31, zmm30, [rsi + 16]` is 11 bytes: it has to use a disp32 to encode `+16`, because it's not a multiple of 64.  But the same instruction with `xmm` registers could use a `disp8`.

See Intel's manuals for the full details.

---

## Special short-forms of the most common instructions

To save code-size, 8086 (and later x86) provides special encodings with no ModR/M byte for some very common instructions.  If the instruction isn't one of these, it uses a ModR/M byte

- add/adc/sub/cmp/test/and/or/xor/etc.  AL/AX/EAX with an immediate of the same size as the register.  e.g. `and eax, imm32` (5 bytes) or `and al,imm8` (2 bytes).  But there's no special encoding for `and eax, imm8`; that still has to use the 3-byte `and r/m32, imm8` encoding.  Using `al` can be very good for code-size when working with 8-bit data, especially if you've avoided or aren't worried about [partial-register stalls or false dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) causing performance problems.
- shift/rotate with a count of 1: 8086 didn't have imm8 rotates, only by `cl` or by an implicit 1, so there are opcodes like `shl r/m32,1` where the `1` is implicit.

  Using the `imm8` encoding has performance implications: [potential stalls on P6-family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter) because it doesn't check if the imm8 is zero until execution.  But the `rol r32,1` short form is 2 uops, vs. 1 for `rol r32, imm8` (even if the imm8 is 1) on Sandybridge-family including Skylake.  The `rcl r32,1` short form is much faster than with an imm8.  ([3 uops vs. 8 on Skylake](http://agner.org/optimize/)).

And **several where the register is encoded in the low 3 bits of the instruction byte**, effectively dedicating 8 bytes of opcode coding space to making the register-operand form of these instructions 1 byte shorter.

- `mov r8, imm8`: 2 bytes instead of 3 for the general `mov r/m8, imm8` encoding.
- [`mov r32, imm32`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOV): 5 bytes instead of 6 bytes for `mov r/m32, imm32`.  Fun fact: in x86-64, the REX.W=1 version of the short-form opcode is the only instruction that can use a 64-bit immediate.  10-byte `mov r64, imm64`.  The REX.W=1 version of the `r/m32` opcode still uses a 32-bit immediate (sign-extended like usual), so `mov rax, -1` is best encoded that way, taking 7 bytes vs. 5-byte `mov eax,-1`.  (Or if optimizing for code-size, see also [Set all bits in CPU register to 1 efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently).)
- [`push`/`pop` register](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PUSH), 1 byte vs. 2 bytes for the `pop r/m32` encoding.
- `push`/`pop` segment registers (other than FS/GS).  Although there isn't a r/m16 encoding for these.
- [`inc r32`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/INC) / [`dec r32`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/DEC) (16/32-bit mode only: the 0x4X bytes are REX prefixes in x86-64, so `inc eax` has to use the 2-byte `inc r/m32` encoding).
- [`xchg eax, reg`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/XCHG):  This is where `0x90 nop` comes from: the short-form of `xchg eax,eax` (or in 16-bit mode, `xchg ax,ax`).  In x86-64, 90 `nop` is not also `xchg eax,eax`, because that would zero-extend EAX into RAX.  Instead, it has [its own instruction-set manual entry](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/NOP).

  `xchg reg,reg` is never used by compilers, and is [usually not faster than 3 `mov` instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766444/why-is-xchg-reg-reg-a-3-micro-op-instruction-on-modern-intel-architectures/45870933#45870933), so it would be nice if we had those 7 opcode bytes back for more useful future extensions.  (Or 8 if `nop` was moved to a different opcode...).  It was more useful in 8086 when the accumulator was "more special", e.g. `cbw` to sign-extend AL into AX was the only (good) way because `movsx` didn't exist.  And only 1-operand `mul` / `imul` was available.

`xchg eax, r32` is still great for code-golf, e.g. [GCD in 8 bytes of x86 32-bit machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364).  See also my other code-golf answers for various code-size tricks (mostly at the expense of performance; that's the point of code-golf).

**I think this covers all the single-byte special cases of instructions that also have `r/m32` encodings.**

---

**This answer isn't meant to be exhaustive**.  I haven't talked about more recent instructions much, and there are lots of special cases for rare instructions.  The rules for when a REX prefix or operand-size prefix are required are pretty straightforward.  Here's are some more general rules:

- SSE1/SSE3 `ABCps` instructions have 2-byte opcodes (0F xx)
- SSE2 integer / double-precision instructions generally have 3-byte opcodes (66 0F xx or similar)
- SSSE3/SSE4.x instructions have 4-byte opcodes (3 mandatory prefixes)

**VEX-coded instructions can use a 2-byte VEX prefix** if the SSE version is SSE3 or earlier, *and* the 2nd source register isn't a "high" register (xmm/ymm8-15).  The XMM and YMM versions of the same instruction are always the same size.  (But [prefer xmm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713273/is-vxorps-zeroing-on-amd-jaguar-bulldozer-zen-faster-with-xmm-registers-than-ymm) with implicit zero-extension instead of explicit ymm when you don't care or want the high half zeroed.)

```
vpxor  ymm8,ymm8,ymm5    ; 2-byte VEX
vpxor  ymm7,ymm7,ymm8    ; 3-byte VEX
vpxor  ymm7,ymm8,ymm7    ; 2-byte VEX
```

So we can use "high" registers as the destination or first source without needing a 3-byte VEX, but not as the 2nd source (3rd operand overall).  For commutative operations, you can save size by putting the low8 one as the 2nd source.

Note that for 4-operand instructions like [`vblendvps`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/BLENDVPS), the 4th operand is encoded in an `imm8`.  So it's still the 3rd operand (2nd source), *not* the last operand, which affects what size VEX prefix is needed.  But `blendvps` is SSE4.1, so it always needs a 3-byte VEX prefix anyway to represent the `66.0F3A` encoding of the prefix field.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the op-code is built with (at least) two criteria in mind

- the frequency of the op-code (put it on 1 byte if frequently used in programs, and if possible)
- the information necessary for the op-code to function (if you need an absolute address, the code cannot be encoded on a unique byte)

Also,

- between the initial 8088 to the latest Intel processors (3 decades) a lot of new instructions have been created, and some, while frequently appearing in programs, could not be coded on one single byte, because the whole 256 values were reserved.

Besides the link provided in another answer (that lists specifically the size of a code), see also the [processors history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this isn't something you need to know from one instruction to the next when programming in assembly language. If it ever matters (such as if you're trying to fit some particular code into a constrained space), you can look at the listing output from the assembler, or a disassembly listing.

Answer (score 1):

From my 6510 assembly days, the answer usually pertained to operand addresses and offsets.  Opcodes were always 1 byte for the 6510.  Addresses were always two bytes.  If the Opcode required one address, then I knew the total size was three bytes.  If two addresses were specified, then I knew the total size was 5 bytes.

As for offsets, the space they occupied was contingent on the length of the branch.  So consider this:

```
bne FooBar
```

If the "Foobar" offset was pointing to an address that was less than 128 bytes away, then the operand was a single byte.  If the offset pointed to an address beyond that, then a full address was needed.  A full address was no longer an offset, and of course addresses occupied two bytes.

So in this latter case, it might not be easy to tell if the opcode + operand required two or three bytes.

So I guess, sometimes you can tell and other times it isn't so obvious.

Comment: You can only have 1 16-bit operand for a maximum instruction size of 3 bytes on the 6502. And conditional branches does not have a long version, so they are always 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can consult the intel dev manual to figure out the size
2. probably easier if you are trying to understand a specific executable: use gdb or `objdump -d`

In gdb, you can `disas /rs <location>` it's going to interleave source code with assembly + machine code

Comment: `objdump -drwC -Mintel` is nice; `-w` disables line-wrapping of the machine-code hexdump part.  Or you can put the instructions in a file and do `nasm -felf64 -l/dev/stdout foo.asm` to make a listing to stdout.  But NASM doesn't leave spaces between bytes in the machine-code hexdump, so longer instructions get painful to read.   e.g. `660F380087D2040000      pshufb xmm0, [rdi+1234]` (and that could have been longer with a RED prefix and/or SIB byte).  You can put a `nop` on the next line so there is one, and look at the addresses in the hexdump, or do `size: db $-$$` or something.

Comment: In practice what I often do is `nasm -f elf64 foo.asm && objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o`.  I have a shell script ([`asm-link`, posted in an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)) that does that; it actually also links it into a static executable with `ld`, which is convenient for building one-file programs as experiments, and to single-step them in GDB even if I don't bother to include code to exit cleanly.  So `asm-link -dn foo.asm` to assemble with NASM and disassemble with objdump.

Comment: just found out that gdb can do both assembly+machine code this is going to be the best option for me because GDB is interactive. also I saw that obj dump in my machine is x86 only and gdb is multi arch and I can save my preferred x86 asm flavor

Comment: `llvm-objdump -d` is multi-arch if you need that, unlike GNU Binutils which only supports the one arch chosen at config time.  GDB being interactive is a downside for throwing an instruction in a text file and assembling + disassembling, or for looking at instruction lengths in a function you're working on.

Comment: I don't get the second part, what's missing in gdb regarding "looking at instruction lengths"

Comment: Nothing's missing from GDB, it's just a pain (less convenient) to have to start up an interactive GDB session vs. running one shell script that assembles + disassembles the instructions in a text file.  e.g. `cat > foo.asm` / type a couple things and control-D / `asm-link -dn foo.asm` takes me like 10 seconds total, and doesn't take much space in my terminal history.  (Especially since I can alt+. to recall the foo.asm on the next command line.)

Comment: hmm, I just tried this, you can totally pipe into gdb like this `echo "disas schedule" | gdb vmlinux`. But yes, when gdb has to load sources it's a lot slower