# How does a compiler, say gcc, version built years ago can still compile for a processor released recently?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compiler-construction, intel, compiler-optimization

Let's say I take a compiler: gcc 4.8. And processor from intel, let's say skylake or some other fancy new family.

checking this question: [How to see which flags -march=native will activate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470257/how-to-see-which-flags-march-native-will-activate); if I do `gcc -march=native -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1`, this will spout out some flags for the host machine, which is the above processor, skylake.

How does gcc know what flags to enable disable... when 4.8 was released before skylake processors were out? What about other newer family of processors?

Consequently, next question is upgrading the compiler to latest necessary for it **accurately and optimally** compile for target processor which is new?

The question isn't really specific to gcc/intel, I would like to know how others maintain synchronicity between processor and compiler too.

Comment: It can only happen if the new processor is specifically designed to be backwards compatible with older models.

Comment: "this will spout out some flags for the host machine, which is the above processor, skylake." Are you saying that if you run that command using gcc 4.8, the resulting command line includes `-march=skylake`? Are you sure you're really invoking gcc 4.8?

Comment: @sepp2k march=native on gcc 4.8. I don't think gcc 4.8 has march=skylake support.

Comment: @themagicalyang I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying. What exactly is the output you see when you run `gcc -march=native -E -v - </dev/null 2>&1 | grep cc1`? I'd expect it to contain something like `-march=haswell`  or `-march=broadwell` (whichever is the latest one that 4.8 supports). I would not expect `-march=skylake` (unless the latest version of 4.8 added support for that, perhaps) and I definitely would not expect `-march=native` (`cc1` does not understand `-march=native`).

Comment: @sepp2k 4.8 doesn't even understand broadwell. it has `march=core-avx2` and `mtune=generic`. on the broadwell i just ran it on.

Comment: @themagicalyang So what makes you say that it will "spout out some flags for the host machine, which is the above processor, skylake"? If the output says `march=core-avx2`, then it's apparently spouting flags for core-avx2 - not skylake. Or are you asking how it knows to use `march=core-avx2` for a skylake CPU?

Comment: The latter. Or in fact it should have had march=skylake but it doesn't and it led me to this question. Whether my compilation is even optimal, whether upgrading compilers is necessary, how does compiler know which flags to enable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Old compilers *don't* know how to tune for new microarchitectures.**  (And are also missing out on better optimization in general:  New versions of gcc/clang usually add new optimizations that help across the board, e.g. gcc8 can coalesce loads/stores of multiple adjacent small variables or array elements into a single 4 or 8-byte load or store.  This helps on everything.)

They can also only use ISA extensions they know about.

**They can make *correct* code because new x86 CPUs are still x86, and are backwards compatible with code for older CPUs<sup>1</sup>**.  Same with ARM.  The ARMv8 ISA is backwards compatible with ARMv7, ARMv6, and so on, so new ARM CPUs can run existing ARM binaries.  (There are some AArch64 CPUs that dropped support for 32-bit mode, but nevermind that.)

> Consequently, next question is upgrading the compiler to latest necessary for it accurately and optimally compile for target processor which is new?

**Yes, you want your compiler to at least know about your CPU for tuning options.**

**But yes, always, even when your CPU isn't new**.  New compiler versions often benefit old CPUs, too, but yes a new set of SIMD extensions to auto-vectorize with can lead to potentially large speedups for code that spends a lot of time in one hot loop.  Assuming that loop auto-vectorizes well.

e.g. Phoronix recently posted [GCC 5 Through GCC 10 Compiler Benchmarks - Five Years Worth Of C/C++ Compiler Performance](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gcc5-gcc10-benchmarks&num=1) where they benchmarked on an i7 5960X (Haswell-E) CPU. I think GCC5 knows about `-march=haswell`.  GCC9.2 makes  measurably faster code than even gcc8 on some benchmarks.

But I can pretty much guarantee it's not *optimal*!!  Compilers are good over large scales but there's usually something a human can find in a single hot loop, if they know the low level details of optimizing for a given microarchitecture.  It's merely as good as you're going to get from any compiler.  (Actually performance regressions exist, so even that's not always true.  File a missed-optimization bug if you find one).

---

### `-march=native` does two separate things

- CPU feature detection to enable stuff like `-mfma` and `-mbmi2`.  This is easy on x86 with the [CPUID instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid).  **GCC will enable all extensions it knows about that are supported by the actual CPU**.  e.g. I think GCC4.8 was the first GCC to know about any AVX512 extensions, so you might even get some AVX512 auto-vectorization on an Ice Lake or Skylake-avx512.  Whether it does a good job or not is another matter, for anything non-trivial.  But no AVX512 with GCC4.7.
- **CPU type detection to set `-mtune=skylake`.**  This depends on GCC actually recognizing your specific CPU as something it knows about.  **If not, it falls back to `-mtune=generic`**.  It might detect (with CPUID) your L1/L2/L3 cache sizes and use that to influence some tuning decisions like inlining / unrolling, instead of using a known size for `-mtune=haswell`.  I don't think that's a big deal; current compilers don't AFAIK introduce cache-blocking optimizations to matmul loops or things like that, and that's where knowing cache sizes really matters.

CPU type detection can also use CPUID on x86; the vendor-string and model / family / stepping numbers uniquely identify the microarchitecture.   ([(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID), [sandpile](https://sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm), [InstLatx64](http://instlatx64.atw.hu/), https://agner.org/optimize/)

x86 is very much designed to support single binaries that run on multiple microarchitectures and might want do to runtime feature detection / dispatching.  So an efficient / portable / extensible CPU detection mechanism exists in the form of the CPUID instruction, introduced in Pentium and some late 486 CPUs.  (And thus baseline for x86-64.)

Other ISAs are more often used in embedded uses where code gets recompiled for the specific CPU.  They mostly don't have as good support for runtime detection.  GCC might have to install a handler for SIGILL and just try running some instructions.  Or query the OS which knows what's supported, e.g. Linux's `/proc/cpuinfo`.

---

**Footnote 1**:

For x86 specifically, its main claim to fame / reason for popularity is strict backwards compatibility. A new CPU that fails to run some existing programs would be a lot harder to sell, so vendors don't do that. They'll even bend over backwards to go beyond the on-paper ISA docs to make sure existing code keeps working. As former Intel architect Andy Glew said: [All or almost all modern Intel processors are stricter than the manual.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395557/observing-stale-instruction-fetching-on-x86-with-self-modifying-code/18388700#18388700) (For self-modifying code, and in general).

Modern PC motherboard firmwares even still emulate the legacy hardware of an IBM PC/XT when you boot in legacy BIOS mode, as well as implementing a software ABI for disk, keyboard, and screen access.  So even bootloaders and stuff like GRUB have a consistent backwards-compatible interface to use, before they load a kernel which has actual drivers for the real hardware that's actually present.

A modern PC can I think still run real MS-DOS (the operating system) binaries in 16-bit real mode.

Adding new instruction opcodes without breaking backwards compat makes variable-length x86 machine code instructions ever more complex, and careless / anti-competitive developments in x86's history haven't helped, leading to more bloated instruction encodings for SSSE3 and later, for example.  See Agner Fog's article [Stop the instruction set war](https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25).

Code that depended on `rep foo` to decode as `foo` can break, though: Intel's manuals are pretty clear that random prefixes *can* cause code to misbehave in future.  This makes it safe for Intel or AMD to introduce new instructions that decode in a known way on old CPUs, but do something new on newer CPUs.  Like `pause` = `rep nop`.  Or transactional memory HLE uses prefixes on `lock`ed instructions that old CPUs will ignore.

And prefixes like VEX (AVX) and EVEX (AVX512) are carefully chosen to not overlap with valid encodings of instructions, especially in 32-bit mode.  See [How does the instruction decoder differentiate between EVEX prefix and BOUND opcode in 32-bit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853237/how-does-the-instruction-decoder-differentiate-between-evex-prefix-and-bound-opc).  This is one reason why 32-bit mode can still only use 8 vector registers (zmm0..7) even with VEX or EVEX which allow ymm0..15 or zmm0..31 respectively in 64-bit mode.  (In 32-bit mode, a VEX prefix is invalid encodings of some opcode.  In 64-bit mode, that opcode isn't valid in the first place to the later bytes are more flexible.  But to simplify decoder HW they aren't fundamentally different.)

**[MIPS32r6 / MIPS64r6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64_Release_6) in 2014 is one notable example that's *not* backwards compatible**.  It rearranged a few opcodes for instructions that stayed the same, and removed some instructions to reuse their opcode for other new instructions, e.g. branches without a delay slot.  This is highly unusual and only makes sense for CPUs that are used for embedded systems (like current MIPS).  Recompiling everything for MIPS32r6 is not a problem for an embedded system.

---

**Some compiles *can* make binaries that do *runtime* CPU detection and dispatching so they can take advantage of whatever a CPU supports**, but still of course only for extensions that the compiler knows about when it compiles.  The AVX+FMA machine-code version of a function has to be there in the executable, so a compiler from before those were even announced wouldn't have been able to create such machine code.

And before real CPUs with the features were available, compiler devs hadn't had a chance to tune code-gen for those features yet, so a newer compiler might make better code for the same CPU features.

GCC has some support for this, via [its `ifunc` mechanism](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC), but IIRC you can't do that without source changes.

Intel's compiler (ICC) I think *does* support multi-versioning some hot functions when auto-vectorizing, with just command-line options.

Answer (score 1):

It can only happen if the new processor is specifically designed to be backwards compatible with older models.

Forget gcc for a moment. You have a compiled X86 binary from year 2000, say, an executable built for the original Windows NT. Will a Skylake CPU run it? You betcha. Will an Itanium CPU run iit? Nope, it is not designed to do that. It is a completely different architecture

Now that executable most probably wouldn't use the Skylake efficiently, but that's the whole point of evolving architectures and introducing new instructions.

Returning to gcc, `-march=native` is not magic. It cannot possibly divine out the new instructions and new timings. It simply selects the "best" instruction set it knows that is supported by the CPU it runs on. How it's done is architecture specific. X86 CPUs can be queried about their capabilities with the the [CPUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction. Other architectures may do it differently.

To put it another way, `-O3 -march=native` optimizes for the machine you compiled on, so it's good when you're compiling code to run on the build host.  A binary built with `-march=native` on a Nehalem system is essentially the same as one built with `-march=nehalem` on *any* system.  `-march=native` might detect your specific L3 cache size instead of using a default for that, if any GCC tuning decisions (like inlining or unrolling) depend on L3 size.  Except if you run an old compiler on a new CPU it doesn't recognize, you get feature detection for stuff like `-mavx` but for tuning only `tune=generic`.

None of this can take advantage of new features like AVX2 or BMI2 when running on a Skylake or Ice Lake system.  And some specific tuning decisions that were good on Nehalem might be sub-optimal on a different CPU.  (Although this is less likely; Intel mostly maintains backwards compatibility for performance as well as correctness.  Getting everyone to recompile everything for P4 didn't work out so they usually try to make existing binaries run well on new CPUs.)

---

Some compiles *can* make binaries that do *runtime* CPU detection and dispatching so they can take advantage of whatever a CPU supports, but only for extensions that the compiler knows about when it compiled.  The AVX+FMA machine-code version of a function has to be there in the executable, so a compiler from before those were even announced wouldn't have been able to create such machine code.  And before real CPUs with the features were available, compiler devs hadn't had a chance to tune code-gen for those features yet, so a newer compiler might make better code for the same CPU features.

Comment: "It simply selects the architecture gcc was built for. Not the architecture it currenntly runs on." That's not true. It will detect the CPU that you're running GCC on or the closest variant it knows.

Comment: Are you saying that a older compiler can compile suboptimally for new architectures?

Comment: Whether the compilation is "optimal" or "suboptimal" will depend on the precise code. You certainly cannot *expect* it to be optimal for a processor which the compiler doesn't explicitly support.

Comment: Hmm, I ended up adding quite a lot of text to expand on the `-march=native` idea in what was your last paragraph.  But yes, x86's main claim to fame / reason for popularity is strict backwards compatibility.  A new CPU that fails to run some existing programs would be a lot harder to sell, so vendors don't do that. They'll even bend over backwards to go beyond the on-paper ISA docs to make sure existing code keeps working.  e.g. former Intel architect Andy Glew said so in [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](//stackoverflow.com/a/18388700)

Comment: After reading the question more carefully, I think much of this is tangential to what the OP was asking; oops.  I posted my own answer.