# How to calculate x86 code mov offset (RIP-relative machine code)?

Tags: assembly, x86, offset, addressing-mode, position-independent-code

1. How to calculate x86 code mov offset(machine code)? please also give an example !!
2. I want to input full address. Anyway make it possible? Address: 7FFB4AB12910, I want something like this: 48 8B 0D 352047A4B4FF07

```
7FFB4A0A0003 - 48 8B 0D 0629A700     mov rcx,[7FFB4AB12910]
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by “calculate mov offset.”  Can you explain what you need in detail?  Note that no standard addressing mode supports a 64 bit displacement.  Either load the address into a register first, or use the `mov rax, moff64` opcode for this purpose (e.g. `mov rax, [7FFB4AB12910]`).  This instruction can only be used with the A register (`al/ax/eax/rax`).

Comment: @fuz 1.sorry!! it is "calculate the offset of code mov ".

Comment: @fuz 2. 7FFB4AB12910 - 7FFB4A0A0003 = A7290D.  It does not match the  offset(A72906). any thing wrong?

Comment: Recall that the offset is computed relative to the beginning of the next instruction.  Also note that x86 instructions are encoded in little endian, so `06 29 A7 00` is `0x00A72906`.  If you account for these two things, you'll see that the instruction is encoded correctly.

Comment: Thanks you so much.  I would like ask one more question that how to  calculate the size of instruction in assembly?

Comment: For x86, this is challenging.  You basically have to decode the instruction completely to find out how long it is.  Use a library like libcapstone if possible.  There are some questions on this subject on this site, but they all boil down to “good luck.”

Comment: For example, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802339/417501).