# Disassembler Code

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, disassembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a disassembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924303/how-to-write-a-disassembler)

I would like to start writing a dis-assembler. Can you help me with right start. I searched the forum and most of them are for a dis-assembler program.

The reason I want to start writing one is I would like to have some customized features to address my requirements.

Edit:
This is to dis-assemble an IL code generated by .NET

Comment: For .NET are you looking to disassemble to ILCode? Or CPU native assembly?

Comment: Why not disassemble a disassembler :)

Comment: I'm mostly curious to know what requirements you have that aren't met by commercial disassemblers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you need directly available via reflection in .Net - up to getting bytes with IL code for given method for given class. Next step is to parse IL and usually [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) is recommended to do so (also can be done from scratch based on IL documentation).

Check also this question [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425973/open-source-alternatives-to-reflector) that lists other existing IL disassemblers.